# FormBaseCell' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using SwiftForms library from GitHub. I recently upgraded my xcode project to Swift 3 and fixed several errors after that. I also made sure to issue `pod update` to make sure SwiftForms is up to date (how do I check if I have the latest version?).

One of the error I can't seem to solve is this:

[image]

When I go to the description of FormBaseCell:
[image]

I can see that the class `FormBaseCell` is only available for ios 10.

How do solve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minimum deployment iOS version is less than 10.0, that's why this error comes.

A lines with

```
public typealias ...
```

are compiled and run on SDK lower than 10.0 as well. In this case it could be missing in your product.